Filtering an Observable Collection in WPF MVVM via ICollectionView
I have an observabelCollection of a data object:
public ObservableCollection<GistViewModel> Gists { get => gists; set => SetProperty(ref gists, value); }

Each GistViewModel has  the following:
public BindingList<GistFileViewModel> GistFiles { get => gistFiles; }

In terms of what this represents, each Gist has a collection of GistFiles. I am mapping this onto a TreeViewControl (root being Gists, Child being GistFiles) via the following xaml (abridged):
<!-- GistLevel -->
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:GistViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GistsFiles}">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GistFiles, Converter={StaticResource GistFilesToFirstFilenameConverter}}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
    
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<!-- GIST FILE LEVEL -->

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:GistFileViewModel}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,0,2,0" Text="{Binding Filename}"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<TreeView x:Name="GistsTV" ItemsSource="{Binding Gists}"/>

This works successfully. Now I am trying to introduce a filter feature. I have followed a guide online somewhere which advises using ICollectionView. I implement this thus:
public ICollectionView GistsView { get => CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Gists); }

private async Task GetAllGistsAsync()
{    
    Gists = await gistManager.LoadGistsAsync();
    GistsView.Refresh();
}

And changing my xaml to:
<TreeView x:Name="GistsTV" ItemsSource="{Binding GistsView}"/>

I'm just trying to get the default list presented first. However, this does not work. No list items are displayed.
GistFilesToFirstFilenameConverter doesn't get called when Binding =  GistsView
The full code is here: https://github.com/stigzler/VisGist/blob/master/VisGist/ToolWindows/MainWindow.xaml
What am I missing?

Please, next time post a minimal reproducible example. Those one-line code snippets are terrible if you have to review faulty code, if that makes sense. Context (for example initialization, DataContext etc.) always matters. It also doesn't help to post a link to the complete project. You have to make the effort to create a new project for your question that makes it easy for others to focus on/understand the relevant code and that allows a reasonable code review. It's also in your own interest.

You don't bind explicitly to an ICollectionView. The binding already does this for you by default. Just filter/sort/group the items using the default ICollectionView This should also fix your issues. No need to call ICollectionView.Refresh at any point.
To make it clear why your code isn't working:

You bind to the GistsView read-only property which returns the default collection view. This property never gets updated. Calling ICollectionView.Refresh does not raise any PropertyChanged notification to notify the TreeView to fetch a new collection view. It's a totally redundant call in your code.
In GetAllGistsAsync you replace the ObservableCollection instance (which you shouldn't do because of the performance costs. Replacing the source collection triggers the ItemsControl to completely re-render itself. Instead, you must reuse the instance by modifying it Clear/Remove and Add/Replace). Just define the binding source collection as read-only to prevent accidental replacement of the current instance.
Updating the Gists property will also introduce a completely new default collection view. However, you never trigger the TreeView to pull the new default collection view. Hence, the TreeView is binding to an outdated collection view. As a result, any filtering applied to the new collection view will not be displayed in the TreeView.

Fixes

Bind the TreeView to the Gists property. The TreeView will implicitly bind to the default collection view and therefore update itself when you apply any filtering or sorting to the default collection view.
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Gists}" />


Update the existing Gists collection. To further improve the performance, make sure that gistManager.LoadGistsAsync does not call ToList and instead returns a plain enumerable (to avoid the additional enumeration of the complete collection)
private async Task GetAllGistsAsync()
{    
  IEnumerable<GistViewModel> newGists = await gistManager.LoadGistsAsync();

  // Update the existing instance to significantly improve the responsiveness of the UI
  this.Gists.Clear();
  foreach (GistViewModel gist in newGists)
  {
    this.Gists.Add(gist);
  }
}

private void FilterGists()
{    
  ICollectionView gistsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Gists);
  gistsView.Filter = GistsFilterDelegate;
}




As much as an excellent answer this is, OP's issue is with how to filter said CVS.

From his question it appears he knows how to filter the data that's why he introduced the ICollectionView. But it doesn't work. It can't work because he's not using the correct ICollectionView instance. My answer explains that and shows how to fix it by not creating new collection instances to replace data. Instead, he must reuse the same collection instance. Now the ICollectionView is always the one that belongs to the source collection.
